# How would you describe someone as intelligent using a similar phrase to "she has fire in her belly"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm writing a speech about someone and I would like to describe them as intelligent using a similar phrase to the way that "she has fire in her belly" would describe her as being passionate and driven.

Something along the lines of

> She has fire in her belly and **{something} in her head**.

Comment: Lots of grey matter?

Comment: ...and brilliance in her brain.

Comment: @WeatherVane I like "brilliance" I think I can do something with that, thanks.

Comment: @Xanne this is hilarious but not quite the tone (this time!) haha

Comment: Good, note I used 'brain' instead of 'head' for alliteration.

Comment: It wasn’t intended to be humorous. “ The grey matter is the seat of a human’s unique ability to think and reason. The grey matter is the place where the processing of sensation, perception, voluntary movement, learning, speech and cognition takes place.” (Cleveland Clinic)

Comment: ' ... and oil in her can.'

Answer (score 1):

I suppose one would like to preserve a certain parallelism in the form of the images used, and thus I'd try to supply a term as in the following.

- She has *fire* in her belly and *sparks* in her head.